# Sending Object and File in asp.net via single request without IFormFile property

Tags: asp.net, typescript, asp.net-web-api, fetch-api

I have a simple controller responsible for CRUD operations, a Pet model and I am using fetch API to send a request in javascript to the endpoint. The body of the request is a FormData object which contains the file and the model, but this does not seem to work, as I get Error code "400 Bad Request". I also tried the same thing using Postman and the result is the same. Upon inspecting the response body, in the errors section I get

```
"errors": {
    "model.Name": [
        "The Name field is required."
    ]
 }
```

I want to send both my model and a file together in a single request. I found some solutions online, but there people added an extra property of type "IFormFile" to their models, whereas I don't want to touch my models and tie them to IFormFile, because they are also supposed to be used outside the context of Web.

I have the following model:

```
public class Pet
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My PUT controller method in PetsController looks as follows:

```
    [HttpPut("{id:guid}")]
    public ActionResult EditPet(Guid id, [FromForm]Pet model)
    {
        ArgumentNullCheck(model);
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Request recieved to edit pet with id {id}");
            //Update model in repo
            if (Request.Form.Files.Count != 0)
            {
                IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                //Store file locally.
            }
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error: {e.Message} when attempting to edit pet with id {id}");
            return UnprocessableEntity();
        }
    }
```

I think this is enough for the PostMan request, but just in case, my fetch request looks like this:

```
    class Pet
    {
         name : string;
         id : string;
         constructor()
         {
             this.name = "";
             this.id = "";
         }
    }

    let model = new Pet();
    model.id = //some GUID;
    model.name = "Cheddar";
    let payLoad = new FormData();
    payLoad.append("model", JSON.stringify(model));
    let file = getFileSomehow();
        if (file)
        {
            payLoad.append("file", file);
        }
    let response: Response; 

        try
        {
            response = await fetch("../Pets/model.id",
                {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': "multipart/form-data"
                    },
                    body: payload
                });
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            console.error(`Error processing update request, ${err}`);
            return;
        }
```

A workaround I thought of is to send two separate requests, but I would rather keep things contained and ideally - send them as once. Any suggestions are appreciated (: .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it consists of using Request.Form to access the File and to deserialize the value of the model, also retrieved from Request.Form.
So, with this in mind, the controller should look like so:

```
[HttpPut("{id:guid}")]
public ActionResult EditPet(Guid id)
{
    Pet model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pet>(Request.Form["model"]);
    ArgumentNullCheck(model);
    try
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Request recieved to edit pet with id {id}");
        //Update model in repo
        if (Request.Form.Files.Count != 0)
        {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            //Store file locally.
        }
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Error: {e.Message} when attempting to edit pet with id {id}");
        return UnprocessableEntity();
    }
}
```